# Two criteria checking in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA macro that searches a range for 'SV' and updates another cell with a certain value ('PEL-SVFC'). I would like the extend this so it only updates that cell if it itself contains a another value (PEL-CD) before it is changed, but I get a type mismatch error.

Below is the macro, the working version as it is currently and the version that raises the type mismatch error:

```
Sub Update3011()
'Update various values in the 3011

'Define some variables
Dim PromoNameColumn As Range
Dim PromoNameColumnAsArray As Variant

Dim AccountNameColumn As Range
Dim AccountNameColumnAsArray As Variant

Dim i As Long

'First action: search cells in column W for text containing "SV". Of those matches, if the cell in column D of that row matches "PEL-CD", replace it with "PEL-SVFC".

Set PromoNameColumn = Range("W2:W" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3011").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
PromoNameColumnAsArray = PromoNameColumn  ' PromoNameColumnAsArray is now array

Set AccountNameColumn = Range("D2:D" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3011").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
AccountNameColumnAsArray = AccountNameColumn  ' AccountNameColumnAsArray is now array

For i = LBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1) To UBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1)

    If InStr(1, PromoNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "SV") Then 'If the range "W2:2" contains SV and the range "D2:D" contains "PEL-CD", continue
        AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1) = "PEL-SVFC"
    End If

Next

AccountNameColumn = AccountNameColumnAsArray

MsgBox ("3011 updated.")

End Sub
```

And the non-working one:

```
Sub Update3011()
'Update various values in the 3011

'Define some variables
Dim PromoNameColumn As Range
Dim PromoNameColumnAsArray As Variant

Dim AccountNameColumn As Range
Dim AccountNameColumnAsArray As Variant

Dim i As Long

'First action: search cells in column W for text containing "SV". Of those matches, if the cell in column D of that row matches "PEL-CD", replace it with "PEL-SVFC".

Set PromoNameColumn = Range("W2:W" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3011").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
PromoNameColumnAsArray = PromoNameColumn  ' PromoNameColumnAsArray is now array

Set AccountNameColumn = Range("D2:D" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3011").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
AccountNameColumnAsArray = AccountNameColumn  ' AccountNameColumnAsArray is now array

For i = LBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1) To UBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1)

    If InStr(1, PromoNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "SV") And InStr(1, AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "PEL-CD") Then 'If the range "W2:2" contains SV and the range "D2:D" contains "PEL-CD", continue
        AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1) = "PEL-SVFC"
    End If

Next

AccountNameColumn = AccountNameColumnAsArray

MsgBox ("3011 updated.")

End Sub
```

So, the bit that causes the error is `And InStr(1, AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "PEL-CD")` in the `if` statement, being the only thing different between the code blocks.

How can I modify this code to add the additional logic check before updating the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. It will not work only in one condition if any of the cells in column D or W contains an error value. Is that the case with your data?

If yes, you may add another condition to check if the value in those two columns are not error values.

```
For i = LBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1) To UBound(PromoNameColumnAsArray, 1)

    If Not IsError(PromoNameColumnAsArray(i, 1)) And Not IsError(AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1)) Then
        If InStr(1, PromoNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "SV") > 0 And InStr(1, AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "PEL-CD") > 0 Then 'If the range "W2:2" contains SV and the range "D2:D" contains "PEL-CD", continue
            AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1) = "PEL-SVFC"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @YowE3K Instr doesn't need >0 to check for True. It will be evaluated to be True if it finds the string being searched and False otherwise.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. Now I see what you were talking about. Good catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

InStr returns the Index where it found the string you are trying to search, so for example

```
InStr(1, "_PEL-CD_", "PEL-CD")
```

would return 2.

In your first code, you are getting really lucky it finds "SV" at the index of 1, and luckily, VBA understands 1 as True, so when you are asking VBA to evaluate a 1 and a 2 as boolean, it will return an Error.

Simply change the code in your 2nd macro to

```
If InStr(1, PromoNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "SV") > 0 And InStr(1, AccountNameColumnAsArray(i, 1), "PEL-CD") < 0 Then
```

Would fix it.

Comment: FWIW - `1 And 2` won't generate an error - it will return `0`, which is equivalent to `False`.  Although `True` is converted to `-1` when being cast to a numeric type, any non-zero value will be converted to a `True` when being cast to a boolean.

Comment: So that explains the behaviour when I pass a non-zero number into an IF. Thank you for clarifying.